# how do i make sure the field is not filled in with empty spaces only?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
  var myNameFilter = /^([a-zA-Z ]+)$/;
  var a = $('#afirstname').val();

  if(a=='') {
    console.log('WT?');  
    return false;
  } else if (!myNameFilter.test(a)) {
      console.log('WT? seriously?'); 
      return false;
  }  
  submit_form();
```

This filtering is not working if someone put the value of `a = '      '` only with some empty spaces.

How to filter that too with the  `myNameFilter`?

Comment: run it through `/^\s*$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim the whitespace using the [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

```
var a = $('#afirstname').val().trim();
```

Names with spaces like `Jan de Derdelinks` will remain. But if they enter `"          Jan de Derdelinks     "` it will become `"Jan de Derdelinks"`

Comment: But some people has name like: Jan de Derdelinks or Geer van bore. with space but full empty spaces should be treated as invalid.

Comment: @YumYumYum That's the beauty of `trim`. It only does whitespace on the outside.

Comment: @YumYumYum Yes, and this will also fail with names with more than one space in between the name segments (wrongly entered that is), e.g. Paul-Van-----Dyk (multiple spaces between Van and Dyk). See my answer for a stronger regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`trim()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) like this

```
var a = '       ';
a.trim() // => ''
```

So you can do

```
  var myNameFilter = /^([a-zA-Z ]+)$/;
  var a = $('#afirstname').val();

  if(!a.trim()) {
    console.log('WT?');  
    return false;
  } else if (!myNameFilter.test(a)) {
      console.log('WT? seriously?'); 
      return false;
  }  
  submit_form();
```

Notice the `if`, the condition `!a.trim()` evaluates to true when the trimmed string is empty, since empty strings are falsy values

Answer (score 0):

I think using [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) and testing the length would be the easiest solution

```
if (a.trim().length) {
  //a has content

} else {
  //a has no content

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNameFilter = /^[a-z|A-Z]+(\s[a-z|A-Z]+){0,}$/,
            name = $('#afirstname').val();

if (myNameFilter.test(name)) {
    submit_form();
}
```

Comment: what if their firstname needs a space?

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you could approach this couls be by taking a string and puttinging it into a function. Lets say that x is your string. We'll find the length, and then we'll find the amount of " "'s in it. If they match, then the string is all blank.

```
`function testForBlank(x) {
    var spaces=x.match(/ /gi).length;
    var length=x.length;
    if (spaces==length) {
        alert("x is all blank");
    } else {
        alert("x is not all blank");
    }
}'
```